# View specified permission isn't replaced by default permission class

Tags: django-rest-framework, permissions, django-permissions, django-rest-framework-jwt

When I set default permission settings to

```
"DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",
    ],
```

and then define different permission for views like

```
@requires_csrf_token
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@api_view(["POST"])
def logout(request):
    pass
```

I expected the view permission to be set as `IsAuthenticated`. But it behaves as `AllowAny`.

- I'm using django rest simple JWT as authentication class.
- The problem is that only the last decorator is applied, and others above, not working. Although I've not found solution for this problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators), your `@permission_classes` decorator

> must come after (below) the `@api_view` decorator

So I would rather try:

```py
@requires_csrf_token
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def logout(request):
    pass
```